# Laravel Query Builder avg() method, float number problem

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Trying to create a 5-star rating system in Laravel.
a star rate is a float number in the range [1 to 5] and it stores successfully in the database.
migration file for rates table in database. ( I've set data type of star column as float)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('rates', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->morphs('rateble');     //creates rateable_id  and  rateable_type
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('set null');
        $table->float('star',2, 1);    //star number is from 0 to 5 
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Then for averaging the rating for a specific product, I am using this query:

```
public function scopeAverageRate($query, $type, $id)
{
    return $query->where('rateble_type', $type)
                 ->where('rateble_id', $id)
                 ->avg('star');
}
```

The problem is, it seems that the `avg()` method cast the result to integer! Is there any way to set this function to work with the float numbers?

e.g. assume there is only one rate for a specific product that equals "0.5" stars then the average rating is "0" instead of  "0.5" !

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: @TsaiKoga Yes. I am using MySQL.

Comment: how do u call this method?

Comment: @TsaiKoga You mean avg() method? 
in the second code block (scopeAverageRate) I called avg() on 'star' column.

Comment: no, I mean how do u call `averageRate()`

Comment: In the related controller, called it in this way:
 $avgRate = Rate::AverageRate($rateble_type, $rateble_id);
$rateble_type  and $rateble_id are defined before this line of code and are equal to "file" and "12" respectively.

Comment: r u sure the specific product that equals to 0.5, because I have tested and it return float.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about it. the rate that is stored in the 'star' column(in database) is 0.5.
actually the rate of the specific product is 0.5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212132/discussion-between-zahra-oveyedzade-and-tsaikoga).

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to write raw sql for the average function like:

```
->selectRaw('CAST(AVG(star) AS DECIMAL(2,1)) AS star_avg')->first()->star_avg;
```

Please note that `star` is the name of a column that we would like to average value of it.

for more information: [here](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/avg-decimal-places-using-cast-within-avg.php)